# how to use android libraries in java project

Tags: java, android

I want to include android libraries in my java project. Actually, I need to run android code in java environment , obviously, this android code would not contain any GUI based action, it will simply use android's predefined libraries ... please suggest to me how android's libraries can be included in java project.
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

Find the JAR file containing the libraries you want to use, and add them to the Java project's build classpath.

However this may not work, depending on the Android classes you want to use.  Some Android classes will have dependencies on the Android platform which will make it unlikely they will work ... or even load ... on a regular Java platform.

Comment: Can I add support for those platform dependent libraries by including Android platform's code, without actually running the platform ???

Comment: @ketan - that is not answerable in general.  It depends on the specific classes that you want to use.  Certainly, some of them will depend on the features of the platform; e.g. Android-specific native libraries.

Answer (score -1):

- If you want to reference a java jar as reference:
  Add that to libs folder in you project
  Right click on project -> Properties - > java Build path -> libraries -> add jars
- If you want reference a android library project then 
  Right click on project -> Properties - > Android - > Add (in lower part of window)

You can use android apis in android library project

Setting up library project [refer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

You can find the difference between jar library and android library [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/)