# No Android dependencies in architecture domain layer

Tags: java, android

I've been reading about Android architecture and separation to Presentation, Domain and Model layers [here](http://saulmm.github.io/when-Iron-Man-becomes-Reactive-Avengers2/) and [here](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/).

In both posts it says that the Domain layer is completely independent of the Android framework:

> "This layer is a pure java module without any android dependencies. All the external components use interfaces when connecting to the business objects."

However, Android provides a lot of utilities (such as TextUtils, android.Log etc...) that can/should be used (in my opinion) in all layers.

Testing (using junit) these kind of classes would required mocking them (meaning, using a lib such as robolectric).

Am I not understanding the pattern? Or by "independent of the Android framework" they mean stuff like Activity, Context, Service, BroadcastReceivers etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The domain layer is business logic. Ideally it isn't coupled to anything, so you could take the same code and run it as a service, or make it a Java Swing client app or anything you would like. And that's one of the major benefits of Java and JVM languages--it's not coupled to a platform (unless you're using platform specific stuff). If you're using Android's Java SDK in your domain logic, you're coupling your valuable business logic to Android platform. Like you identify, the core classes of Android (`Activity`, `Context`, `Service`, etc.) should never be used in this layer. Those are presentation layer constructions.

You can avoid coupling yourself to your platform, but still take advantage of Android's SDK implementation by creating generic interfaces that wrap the Android implementation. For example if you found a function offered by TextUtils that you thought was useful, you would create an interface (even perhaps with the same name):

```
public interface TextUtils {
    CharSequence concat(CharSequence...seqs);
}

public class TextUtilsAndroid implements TextUtils {
    public CharSequence concat(CharSequence...seqs) {
        return android.text.TextUtils.concat(seqs);
    }
}
```

Then, instead of referencing `android.text.TextUtils` directly, you pass a reference to your interface instead. On your Android app, you define `TextUtilsAndroid` and configure your domain logic with an instance of it. If you decide at any point to move your business logic to a Swing app or a web service, you are free to do so, and you can implement `TextUtils` in vanilla Java SE JDK (or even [include an Android jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484345/how-to-use-android-libraries-in-java-project) depending on how interdependent it is on other Android libraries).

Logging should be done the same way. Instead of coupling yourself to Android's logging framework, check out [slf4j-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api) which provides a platform independent logging *interface*, and look at [slf4j-android](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) which provides an Android platform binding for the slf4j interface.

Mocking is not a bad thing. You should mock all external dependencies of every class you're testing. For example, you would mock any instance of `TextUtils` that your domain layer uses, and use the mocking framework's expectations to verify the behavior of your domain class without coupling the test to the behavior of the impl of `TextUtils.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! regarding your TextUtils example, you said that I should use an instance of the new TextUtilsAndroid class. 2 questions:
1. In which layer should I define TextUtilsAndroid? 2.A lot of these utility classes use static methods/consts. Is there a way to avoid passing a reference to an instance, and using the static methods/consts instead?

Comment: @dors 1. That's a good question. TextUtils is a utility that could be used in multiple layers. If you're using it in your domain logic, it should be considered a domain logic class, but segregate it so the rest of the code will compile without Android SDK. 2. My general opinion is static is evil because you end up coupling yourself to a particular implementation of something. E.g. if you found a bug in TextUtilsAndroid, or if you found a more efficient implementation, using an interface will let you swap out the implementation easily (even at runtime). AFAIK static methods don't allow mocking.

Comment: ok, thanks @Samuel, I will keep these items in mind. I will however consider if going "by the book" and having the domain layer a pure java model something that I will fight for, since it adds a lot of complexity to an Android project + the odds of me needing it to really be pure are very slim.